# Delete objects in an array of objects based on the values in an array of values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, redux, reducers

I am trying to add a reducer in redux that deletes multiple items in the state based on an array of values.

Say I have the array

```
const idArray = ["935", "933", "930"];
```

And I would like to delete the objects that have an id property that matches one of the values in the idArray and return a new array with the remaining values.

```
const objectsArray= [
  { 
    name: "Kevin", 
    color: "red", 
    id: "935"
  },
  { 
    name: "Ana", 
    color: "white", 
    id: "815"
  },
  { 
    name: "Maria", 
    color: "silver", 
    id: "035"
  },
  { 
    name: "Victor", 
    color: "red", 
    id: "935"
  },
  { 
    name: "Vanessa", 
    color: "red", 
    id: "933"
  },
]
```

So in this case, i would like to remove the objects that have the names:  `Kevin`, `Vanessa` and `Victor`, and return a new array with `Ana` and `Maria`.

This is what i have in my reducer so far:

```
case PeopleActions.DELETE_PEOPLE:
  if (action.id.length === 1) {
    return state.filter(people =>
      people.id !== action.id[0]
    );
  } else {
    const deletePeople: any = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < action.id.length; i++) {
        return state.filter(poeple =>
          people.id !== action.id[i]
        );
      }
    };
    return deletePeople;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume since `objectsArray` is marked `const` then reassigning a new array is out, which means no `filter()`.

If you need to mutate the array in place, the best option might be to simply loop through the array backwards and splice as you go:

```js
const idArray = ["935", "933", "930"];

const objectsArray= [{   name: "Kevin",   color: "red",   id: "935"},{   name: "Ana",   color: "white",   id: "815"},{   name: "Maria",   color: "silver",   id: "035"},{   name: "Victor",   color: "red",   id: "935"},{   name: "Vanessa",   color: "red",   id: "933"},]

for (let i = objectsArray.length-1; i >=0 ; i--){
    if(idArray.includes(objectsArray[i].id)){
        objectsArray.splice(i,1);
        }
}

console.log(objectsArray);
```